# In python 3.5, when using a argument list as input to subprocess.Popen(), I cannot get correct len(sys.argv)

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, subprocess, sequence

In experiment_script.py, I use a list as input to `subprocess.Popen()`.

```
cmd = [r'.\modified_easy.py', training_libsvm_files[training_index], testing_libsvm_files[training_index]]
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                     shell = True, # The cmd won't work without this setting in Python 3.3. However, in Python 3.5, this setting is not necessary.
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

In .\modified_easy.py, the number of arguments are checked:

```
if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
    print('Usage: {0} training_file [testing_file]'.format(sys.argv[0]))
    raise SystemExit
```

`experiment_script.py` runs normally in Python3.3. However, after I changed to Python 3.5. The check `len(sys.argv)` fails, and `SystemExit` is raised. I printed out `len(sys.argv)` and found it now becomes 1. So, how does this happen and how to get correct `len(sys.argv)`?

My OS is windows 64 bit.

The result of `len(sys.argv)` is still 1, even if I use `cmd = ' '.join(cmd)` to change the sequence to a string and then input it to `subprocess.Popen()`.

Comment: I am confusing. I have 2 installations of Python 3.3.2 in 2 computers. experiment_script.py works at one computer but fails at the other.

Comment: Try adding `'python'` at the beginning of `cmd`, like `cmd = ['python', '.\modified_easy.py', ...]`.

Comment: @acw1668  I added `'python'` and finally `len(sys.argv)` becomes 3. Thank you very much. But what's the reason? Since there are many places when I call python script without the 'python' keyword. Are there some other easier solutions?

Comment: I called the python script in another script without the 'python' keyword before and it worked. Is adding the 'python' keyword the new standard?

Comment: Sorry, I found it's not about the version of python. It's about the distribution of python. When calling python script without keyword 'python', `len(sys.argv)` gives the wrong result i.e. 1, on Anaconda or WinPython. However, the official python distribution gives the correct result, i.e. 3.

Comment: `Popen` cannot run `modified_easy.py` without `shell=True` in *any* version of Python. You have something bizarre going on if that works. It simply calls `CreateProcess`, which tries and fails to run `modified_easy.py` as a PE executable. Running arbitrary filetypes requires `ShellExecuteEx`, which gets the command to run from registry by looking up the .PY extension to get the associated progid (e.g. `Python.File`) which has a default or "open" verb with a command template.

Comment: Thanks to @eryksun for the explanation of `shell=True`. Can you explain something about the adding of `python` when executing a python script using `Popen`. What's the difference by adding the `python` keyword. And, how this effect the check of `len(sys.argv)` in the script.

Comment: In that case you shouldn't need `shell=True`. `Popen` calls WinAPI `CreateProcess`, which will search the application directory, system directories, and the directories in `PATH` for a file named either `python` or `python.exe`. Since you're running Python, naturally it will find `python.exe` in the application directory. As to `len(sys.argv)`, you'll have to provide a concrete example showing exactly what the command-line is and exactly what the resulting `sys.argv` is for me to suggest an explanation.

Comment: @eryksun Perhaps the command that is associated with the `.py` file extension is incorrect. To debug, create a minimal code example: `import sys; sys.exit(len(sys.argv))` and put it into `nargs.py` file.  Then run `assert subprocess.call(r'\path\to\nargs.py 1 2', shell=True) == 3` and compare it versus `assert call([sys.executable, r'\path\to\nargs.py', '1', '2']) == 3`. Is there a shebang (`#!`) at the top of the `.py` file. What do `assoc .py`, `ftype Python.File` commands show?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, if this is broken by improper use of Explorer's "open with" dialog, then `assoc` and `ftype` won't help. They only show and modify the base system association under `HKLM\Software\Classes`. To modify the user choice setting, select the "open with" dialog's "choose another app". Select "Python" from the list (the py launcher icon has rocket in it) and "always" use this app. Don't "look for another app" because selecting an executable directly creates a new ProgId that doesn't accept command-line arguments.

Comment: @eryksun *«Don't "look for another app" because selecting an executable directly creates a new ProgId that doesn't accept command-line arguments»* might be the likely reason for the behavior described in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @eryksun and @J.F. Sebastian . I did some trials and found how `len(sys.argv)` could not work as expected.

Just as what @eryksun said,

> Select "Python" from the list (the `py` launcher icon has rocket in it) and "always" use this app. Don't "look for another app" because selecting an executable directly creates a new ProgId that doesn't accept command-line arguments.

When running a python script in another script using `subprocess`, if you don't specify the `python` keyword or `sys.executable`, the OS will open the `.py` file according to some file associations. If the OS by default open .py file with the python launcher `py.exe`, then it's OK. If the OS open .py file with `python.exe` then `len(sys.argv)` will fail.

Previously, I installed Anaconda in a computer and there was no py.exe. So, when asked by the "open with" dialog', I chose python.exe. Therefore len(sys.argv) failed.

To solve it, I can either add the `python` keyword or make the OS open .py files using `py.exe`